# Firebase Functions / Cloud SQL (mysql) / Knex accumulates connections

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

We have firebase functions setup to connect to a cloud sql (mysql) instance, everything is working as expected except that the connections to the instance are not pooling. The more connections we send to the website the connections quickly climb until they reach the limit of 100.

`lib/db.ts`

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as knex from 'knex';

const { env } = functions.config();

export default knex({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    ...env.mysql,
    timezone: 'UTC',
    dateStrings: true,
  },
  pool: { min: 1, max: 1 },
});
```

We are also importing this file in the main `index.ts`

```js
import 'lib/db';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about firebase functions, but if firebase functions are spawning new node processes all the time with new knex pools I suppose that with this config one connection per every process is expected. You could change config parameters so that pool  { min: 0 max: 1, idleTimeoutMillis: 1000 } so that  if any of the processes are more than 1 second without making queries the connection is released.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö thank you for the comment, unfortunately every function we have utilizes the db.  Currently we are looking at moving to a one function that routes to our other functions and manages the mysql pool